# Can we get closed form solution for such a problem?

Tags: convexity

\begin{align}\min&\quad\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{A_i}{x_i}\\\text{s.t.}&\quad\sum x_i \le X\\&\quad x_i \ge 0\end{align}

wherein $A_i>0, (i\in\{1,\dots,N\})$ is constant, $x_i, (i\in\{1,\dots,N\})$ is a continuous optimization variable.

Answer (score 5):

If some $A_i$ is negative the problem is unbounded: we can make the objective arbitrarily small by making $x_i$ arbitrarily close to 0.

Assuming $A_i \geq 0$, the optimality is obtained when all $\frac{A_i}{x_i^2}$ are equal (KKT optimality conditions), or equivalently all $\frac{x_i^2}{A_i}$ are equal, and $\sum x_i  = X$ (otherwise you can increase some $x_i$ and reduce the objective).

Stating $x_i = \sqrt{A_i} y$, you can deduce $y = \frac{X}{\sum \sqrt{A_i}}$ from the equality.

Therefore $x_i = \frac{\sqrt{A_i}}{\sum \sqrt{A_j}}X$

Comment: This does not work if some $A_i=0$.

Comment: Yes. I was too lazy to spell it out, but you need an $A_i \gt 0$ for the equality to hold. Thanks

Comment: (As far as I can tell you just need one, though. And if all are zero the problem is trivial)

Comment: In this case all $x_i$ where $A_i=0$ must be 0, just like the general formula

Comment: No, I mean if even one $A_i=0$ your argument that all $A_i/x_i^2$ are equal fails.  Furthermore, you cannot have $x_i=0$ ever because it appears in the denominator of a summand in the objective.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I am so sorry I did not indicate that Ai>0.

Comment: If further constraints Ai/xi<=Bi (i∈{1,...,N}) should be satisfied (Bi is constant), how to get the closed-form solution? Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: This problem is conic quadratic representable.  Here https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/cqo.html#a-resource-constrained-production-and-inventory-problem is a more general version of the problem discussed.

Comment: The case of $\frac{A_i}{x_i} \leq B_i$ is equivalent to $x_i \geq \frac{A_i}{B_i}$, and would result in some variables being saturated at their bound. It's not exactly a closed form solution, but you could solve it iteratively with an active set method : you have a closed-form formula like I did for the variables that are not saturated, and at each step a variable enters or exits the active set. Maybe there is an order that keeps this algorithm at $N$ iterations.